# Oracle 11gR2 grid silent installation: error for privateinterconnects

Tags: software-installation, cluster, oracle-database, private-network

I am installing Oracle grid 11gR2 using silent install with response file. I am getting error after "Collecting interface information for node 1" in logs.

I have a feeling that this could be due to option `oracle.crs.config.privateinterconnects=eth0:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1,eth1:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2`

Here I have specified only for 1 node. Do I need to specify interconnects for both nodes.

`ERROR message: One or more nodes have interfaces not configured with a subnet that is common across all nodes.`

Answer (score 1):

It was a configuration mistake. There needs to be subnet and not ip address or subnet mask in interconnects